# Getting Rid of the Red squiggly Lines in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to integrate API from AntiGate. I downloaded the Jar files from https://github.com/itsimoshka/antigate-java-api and added them to build path. Now when I try running something like:

```
 AntigateConfig config = new DefaultAntigateConfig();
```

I get the squiggly red lines on bottom with the msg Antigate cannot be resolved to a type. So I import all related packages using eclipse.

The code

```
import com.antigate.config.AntigateConfig;
```

is added on top when I hover over code and perform import. But then the import statement on top is underlined. How do I correct it?

I'm assuming I have imported the jars correctly in my project (otherwise I wouldn't be able to click import in eclipse) but perhaps are contained in a different location? However, I'm not sure how to find the location or import them in the correct way.

I also noticed (this may actually be the source of the problem) that most of the files in above URL are not actually Jars but rather regular Java files.

How to I import regular java files to my project (as appose to Jars)?

Thanks

P.S

I already added the files to build path so not sure source of error.

Comment: There's no JAR on website. You have to package it from sources. Did you have any problem when you did it ?

Comment: Thanks. The only jar file I've found is here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-antigate/downloads but this does not contain most of the code/methods. What do you mean package it from sources?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the steps described on the **README** page :

> Installation
>
> - Download sources from https://github.com/itsimoshka/antigate-java-api.git
> - Go to sources directory
> - Run `mvn clean install` (Maven should be installed previously)
> - Get `antigate-java-api-XX.jar` from target folder

Comment: Thanks. I have Maven installed but I didn't get this:   Go to sources directory   and  Run mvn clean install (Maven should be installed previously) - what does it mean?

Comment: You have to install Maven on your machine : https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: I have downloaded Maven through eclipse marketplace. I tried to do a clean install using Run As in eclipse but I don find anything in target folder.

Comment: Was the maven build successfull ?

Comment: If the build was successful, you will see in the logs where the JAR is generated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115219/discussion-between-mickael-b-and-ee-clipse).